# How to maintain view state when navigating between screens in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In an ASP.NET application, I would like the screen state to be preserved when navigating between screens. So if on a screen A I search for something and the data is presented on screen, I then click 'Next' to navigate to screen B, then click 'Back' to navigate back to screen A, the search parameters and results should be again visible.

Are there out-of-the-box solutions for this, or generic patterns for achieving this?

Comment: You could use a JavaScript framework such as [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/), [Angular](https://angularjs.org/), or [React](https://reactjs.org/) to accomplish this, provided it meets your other requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This is not built-in afaik, but i used with success a module called "pagestate" that save the viewstate in session, and restore it.

It doesn't exist anymore on Codeplex, but here is the code
https://pastebin.com/t5BexLpx

First, your pages should inherit from PersistantPage instead of System.Web.UI.Page
Then, to save the current page state before moving to another one, you will call the method

```
RedirectSavingPageState(string url)
```

instead of a standard redirect server side.
When returning on the initial page,its viewstate will be restaured..

Enjoy,